# Performance issues for Query with JOIN and RANK()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote the following SQL Command:

```
SELECT *,  COALESCE (def.route_step, 'Keine Fehlerinformation') as 'Ausfallort'
FROM QS_WIP_Errors err
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               inspect_time, repair_time, serial_number, station, route_step,
               rank() over (partition by def.serial_number order by inspect_time desc) as [Rang]
        FROM dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten def
        WHERE route_step NOT LIKE 'Analyse'
    ) AS def WHERE rang=1) as def
ON err.SERIAL_NUMBER = def.serial_number
WHERE err.state = 2
  AND err.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-06 06:00:00.000' 
  AND err.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000'
```

What I intent to do is:

- from the `QS_WIP_Errors`: get all the records with `state = 2`;
- for a specified period of time;
- join those results by the attribute `serial_number` with corresponding records from the view `dbo.View_QS_Defects_Stammdaten`;
- COALESCE: display '`Keine Fehlerinformationen` in case if the `JOIN doesn't find a match;
- from the `dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten`: get just the newest record for each `def.serial_number` where `rang=1`;
- except for if the last `route_step` would be `Analyse`.

The Query above does everything that it's designed for - but it doesn't do it in the desired time (I aborted it after 30 minutes...)

The strange thing is, that when I skip the time limit (i.e. the line  `AND err.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-06 06:00:00.000' AND err.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000'`) the query is executed within a few seconds (i.e. as desired).

What I tried so far to improve the performance:

- replace the `view_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten` by the original table;
- instead of querying all columns (*) just selecting some single columns
  --> without any improvement

Can anybody give me a hint how I could improve the performance???

Thanks a lot!
I'm working with SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

This is your query:

```
select *,  COALESCE(def.route_step, 'Keine Fehlerinformation') as Ausfallort
from QS_WIP_Errors err left join
     (select *
      from (select distinct inspect_time, repair_time, serial_number, station, route_step,
                   rank() over (partition by def.serial_number order by inspect_time desc) as [Rang]
            from dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten def
            where route_step not like 'Analyse'
           ) as def
      where rang = 1
     ) as def
     on err.SERIAL_NUMBER = def.serial_number
where err.state = 2 AND
      err.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-06 06:00:00.000' AND err.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000';
```

Some observations:

- Performance may be driven by the underlying view, so there may be nothing that can be done at this level.
- `distinct` does not seem to be unnecessary.  If you want only one row, you should be more specific by using `row_number()`.
- An index on `err` would help.

So building the index `QS_WIP_Errors(state, endtime, serial_number)` and writing the query as:

```
select *,  COALESCE(def.route_step, 'Keine Fehlerinformation') as Ausfallort
from QS_WIP_Errors err left join
     (select inspect_time, repair_time, serial_number, station, route_step,
             row_number() over (partition by def.serial_number order by inspect_time desc) as [Rang]
      from dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten def
      where route_step not like 'Analyse'
     ) as def
     on err.SERIAL_NUMBER = def.serial_number and rang = 1
where err.state = 2 AND
      err.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-06 06:00:00.000' AND err.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000';
```

You might also try writing this as an `outer apply`:

```
select *, COALESCE(def.route_step, 'Keine Fehlerinformation') as Ausfallort
from QS_WIP_Errors err outer apply
     (select top 1 inspect_time, repair_time, serial_number, station, route_step
      from dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten def
      where route_step not like 'Analyse' and err.SERIAL_NUMBER = def.serial_number
      order by inspect_time desc
     ) def
where err.state = 2 AND
      err.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-06 06:00:00.000' AND err.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000';
```

Sometimes the `apply` method optimizes better.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Gordon for your reply.
First of all, for your hint with using "distinct" and "row number" - you were actually right and my query above didn´t give me the results i wanted.
I modified it then this way:

```
Select * from (
  select distinct err.SERIAL_NUMBER as 'Err_SERIAL_NUMBER', 
  err.ROUTE_STEP as 'Err_ROUTE_STEP', err.ENDTIME, 
  rank() over (partition by err.serial_Number order by err.endtime asc) as [Rank_err],
  def.*, COALESCE (def.route_step, 'Keine Fehlerinformation') as 'Ausfallort' 
  from QS_WIP_Errors err LEFT JOIN (
  select * from
  (
  select distinct inspect_time as 'DefectsInspectTime', serial_number, station, route_step,  
    rank() over (partition by def.serial_number order by def.inspect_time desc) as [Rank_Def]
    from dbo.View_QS_DEFECTS_Stammdaten def where route_step not like 'Analyse'
  ) as def where Rank_Def=1) as def
  on err.SERIAL_NUMBER = def.serial_number
  where err.state = 2 ) as tblJoin
where tblJoin.Rank_err = 1
AND tblJoin.ENDTIME >= '2014-10-07 06:00:00.000' AND tblJoin.ENDTIME <= '2014-10-08 06:00:00.000'
```

Now i really get the values i wanted. AND as a nice side effect, now the query is executed within few seconds. I cannot really explain it, but it solved the problem. That´s why i marked it as answer